# Evaluate $\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{\iint_\Omega P(x,\,y,\,z)\,dydz+Q(x,\,y,\,z)\,dzdx+R(x,\,y,\,z)\,dxdy}{t^4}$.

Tags: analysis

> Suppose $P(x,\,y,\,z)=Q(x,\,y,\,z)=R(x,\,y,\,z)=f((x^2+y^2)z)$ and $f$ has continuous derivative. Evaluate 
>   $$
> \lim_{t\to0+}\frac{\iint_\Omega P(x,\,y,\,z)\,dydz+Q(x,\,y,\,z)\,dzdx+R(x,\,y,\,z)\,dxdy}{t^4},
> $$
>   where $\Omega$ is the outside surface of $\{(x,\,y,\,z)\vert x^2+y^2\leq t^2,\,z\in[0,\,1]\}$.

I used Gauss Theorem to evaluate it, but could not get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume outside surface includes the planes on the ends. If not, you'll have to subtract off their contribution. By Divergence theorem you get that

$$\iint_\Omega (P,Q,R)\cdot \nu d\sigma = \iiint_{\text{Int}(\Omega)} 2xzf'((x^2+y^2)z)+2yzf'((x^2+y^2)z)+(x^2+y^2)f'((x^2+y^2)z) d^3 x$$

The first two terms are odd functions of $x$ and $y$, respectively, so their contributions to the final integral are $0$ by symmetry. Converting to cylindrical coordinates and computing the integral of the last term:

$$2\pi \int_0^t \int_0^1 r^3 f'(r^2z)dzdr = 2\pi\int_0^t rf(r^2)-rf(0)dr$$

Now plug this in to the integral and use L'Hopital

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{2\pi\int_0^t rf(r^2)-rf(0)dr}{t^4} = \lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{\pi t f(t^2) - \pi tf(0)}{2t^3} = \lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{\pi  f(t^2) - \pi f(0)}{2t^2}$$

Then L'Hopital again

$$= \lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{\pi t f'(t^2) }{2t} = \frac{\pi}{2}f'(0)$$